# Delete button not visible in Huawei for deleting app

Tags: button, huawei-mobile-services

I want to delete the app in Huawei but there is  no button to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, once the application is released or if it is under review, that app cannot be deleted. But you can remove an released app and it can be found from your released app list and click the version to be removed from sale.

Please use below document link for details on deleting and removing the application.

Link removing the app :
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-removeapp-0000001100316676

Link for deleting app : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-deleteapp-0000001146716617